# Is the graph of the Conway base 13 function connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

IVT Property: If $a<b$ and $y$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=y$.

> Theorem. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function with the IVT Property. If the set of discontinuities of $f$ is first category in $\mathbb R$, then the graph of $f$ is connected.

This is an old Theorem. I assume there must be a counterexample if we leave out the first category assumption, though I don't know of any (help!).

There are functions which are discontinuous everywhere and still have connected graphs. F.B. Jones showed that the graph of a function satisfying $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ can be connected, even if the function is discontinuous everywhere.

So now I come to [Conway's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function). It has the IVT property in a rather extreme way: it takes every value on every interval. It is discontinuous everywhere. Is the graph connected?

Comment: This is a great try at a counterexample.  The set of discontinuities of $f$ is all of $\Bbb R$, so it is as far from first category as you can get.  A naive try is to separate the graph into $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$ with $x \le k$ and $y \gt k$.  This fails because any neighborhood of $(k, f(k))$ will include points of the upper half. Now we need to find a path that connects $(k,f(k)+\epsilon)$ to $(k, f(k)-\epsilon)$ without going through any of the points of the graph.

Comment: I think a counterexample can be obtained more easily by modifying the function slightly. Let $f$ be Conway's function. Define $g(x) = f(x) + 1$ if $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = f(x)$ otherwise. The fibres of $g$ are still dense in $\mathbb{R}$ since they differ by only one point each from those of $f$, but $g$ has no fixed points, which gives an easy separation of the graph.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that the fibres of $g$ differ from those of $f$ by finitely many points each.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen that is a good counterexample!

Comment: and you basically proved that taking every value on every interval is not enough to guarantee the graph is connected.

Answer (score 14):

Merely knowing that the base-13 function takes every value in every interval does not tell us whether its graph is connected or not. [Here is an answer by Eric Wofsey](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3274547/14366) that constructs a function with this property and a *connected* graph -- on the other hand a comment by Niels J. Diepeveen explains how any such function can be modified to have a *disconnected* graph without losing the every value-in-every-interval property:

> I think a counterexample can be obtained more easily by modifying the function slightly. Let $f$ be Conway's function. Define $g(x)=f(x)+1$ if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ otherwise. The fibres of $g$ are still dense in $\mathbb R$ since they differ by only one point each from those of $f$, but $g$ has no fixed points, which gives an easy separation of the graph.

So we need to look closer into Conway's particular definition to resolve the matter.

### The graph of the base-13 function is not connected.

In fact it is **totally separated** (and therefore **totally disconnected**), since you can carry out variants of the following construction almost everywhere in the plane, enough to separate any two points.

Let $f$ be [the Conway function as defined in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function). I will construct a continuous function $h:\mathbb [0,1]\to[1,2]$ such that $h(x)\ne f(x)$ everywhere. Then
$$\{(x,f(x))\mid 0<x<1 \land f(x)>h(x)\}$$
is a nontrivial relatively clopen subset of the graph of $f$ (since $f(0)=f(1)=0$), so the graph is not connected.

The construction depends on the fact that the intersection of the graph of $f$ with the rectangle $[0,1]\times[1,2]$ is the union of countably many functions $f_i$ such that

- $f_i$'s domain is a subset of $[0,1]$
- $f_i$ is non-decreasing, and
- $f_i$ is surjective onto $[1,2]$.

Namely, each $f_i$ handles the inputs where the encoded decimal point is in a particular position, with a particular sequence of tridecimal digits in front of it. Each of them looks a bit like the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) with the interior of each plateau removed, such that there is a horizontal gap instead.

The properties of$f_i$ noted above means that it can be *uniquely* extended to a *non-decreasing* $g_i:[0,1]\to[1,2]$. (At points where $f_i(x)$ is not defined, there can only be one possible value of $g_i(x)$ that won't break monotonicity). We have that $g_i(0)=1$, $g_i(1)=2$ and $g_i$ is continuous.

My $h$ will be strictly *decreasing*, with its values chosen such that it intersects each $g_i$ at an $x$-coordinate where $f_i$ is not defined. This prevents it from intersecting each of the $f_i$s and therefore from intersecting all of $f$.

We start by setting $h(0)=2$, $h(1)=1$ and now inductively define a sequence of additional points on $h$. In this phase we maintain the invariants that

- $h$ is defined at finitely many points in $[0,1]$.
- $h(x)$ is (so far) only defined for points where $f(x)=0$.
- Whenever $h(a)$ and $h(b)$ are defined for distinct $a$ and $b$, the slope $\frac{h(a)-h(b)}{a-b}$ will be *strictly* between $-2$ and $0$. (We easily see that it is enough to enforce this between *neighboring points*).

Now in step $i$ we will chose an $x_i$ and $h(x_i)$ which prevents $h$ from meeting $f_i$. Consider the piecewise linear function we get from interpolating linearly between the known points of $h$. It is strictly decreasing, so it intersects $g_i$ at exactly one point. If this happens to be at an already known point of $h$, we don't need to add any point in this step.

Otherwise the points where near the intersection point where the slope condition above will let us place a new $(x_i,h(x_i))$ form an open parallelogram of $[0,1]\times[1,2]$, which contains the intersection point. The set of $x$ such that $(x,g_i(x))$ is in the parallelogram is open and nonempty, and therefore we can chose an $x_i$ in this set with $f(x_i)=0$. Now set $h(x_i)=g_i(x_i)$.

At the end of $\omega$ many steps, we will have defined $h(x)$ for a dense set of $x$s, because each interval on the $x$ axis contains the entire preimage of the interior of $[1,2]$ under at least one of the $g_i$s.

This means that $x\mapsto h(x)+x$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $1$ defined on a dense subset of $[0,1]$, and it therefore extends uniquely to a function on all of $[0,1]$ with the same Lipschitz constant. Subtracting $x$ back out gives us a strictly decreasing continuous $h$ that avoids all $f_i$, as desired.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the height of the gap?

Comment: @Yui, the $y$-coordinate at which the gap happens.

Comment: (This is well defined because $f_i$ is surjective and increasing, so the supremum of the values of $f_i$ to the _left_ of the gap must be the same as the infimum of the values of $f_i$ to the _right_ of the gap).

Comment: I see. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Sorry for being desne, why is the set $\{(x, f(x)) | 0<x<1 \wedge f(x)>h(x)\}$ relatively clopen?

Comment: @YuiToCheng: Because $A=\{(x,y)\mid 0<x<1, y > h(x)\}$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$ (so its intersection with $f$ is open in $f$) and its boundary does not contain any points of $f$ (so the _rest_ of $f$ is contained in the complement of the closure of $A$, which is open in $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: Thanks again. One more question: why is the final function doesn't contain any point of $f_i$?

Comment: @YuiToCheng: Because it is strictly decreasing. 1) We've chosen $x_i$ such that $f_i(x)$ is not defined. 2) For $a<x_i$ we have $f_i(a) \le \sup_{x<x_i} f_i(x) = h(x_i) < h(a)$. 3) For $b>x_i$ we have $f_i(b) \ge \inf_{x>x_i}f_i(x) = h(x_i) > h(b)$. [Per the comment above, these characterizations of $h(x_i)$ are equivalent].

Comment: That makes sense. The slope condition is to make sure $h$ is continuous, right?

Comment: @YuiToCheng: That's right. Without it, a jump discontinuity might build up and ruin everything.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience. You deserve the bounty.